# Convert landscape image to portrait mode when select from UIImagePickerController in iOS6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, ios6, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to convert landscape image to portrait mode when select from `UIImagePickerController` in iOS6.
Please tell suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add autoresizing mask to your image view.
 Try this:- 
 `yourImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;`